# How to delete Rally workspacepermission using REST API?

Tags: rally

Can anybody please explain how to pass reference strings for Delete actions of WorkspacePermission? I tried below,

`DeleteRequest delete = new DeleteRequest("/workspacepermission/9250166251u2788951014w1.js");
where

Workspacepermission id= 9250166251
User Object id= u2788951014
workspace number= w1`

Can anyone tell me how to pass them correctly?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you post what error you are seeing on the above? Your syntax looks good. When I try this, I am seeing: Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: HTTP/1.1 404 Could not determine Web Services Version from ''.

Comment: I should clarify - I'm using the 1.04 version of Java REST library.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your reply! Yes I am getting same exception.I want to delete assigned permissions and I tried with DeleteRequest and UpdateRequest. When I try with DeleteRequest, I get could not determine web service error. Pr

Comment: The pattern defined for validating the requests was allowing only numbers and hence resources like these '9250166251u2788951014w1.js" were failing. After modifying the pattern string in Ref.java to below it worked fine.
private static Pattern refPattern = Pattern.compile(".*?/((?:/*\\w{2,}){1,2})/(\\w+)(?:\\.js\\??.*)*$");

Answer (score 0):

Sharat, nice work finding the issue with the pattern. I've chatted with the Rally developers and went ahead and opened an Issue for the Java RestApi out on the public Github repo:

https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava/issues/5

You can track the resolution there - likely a new build of the jar coming fairly soon.